# How to save Maven Surefire reports through Google Cloud Build

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, google-cloud-build

We have a Java project that we build using Maven.  We use the Surefire plugin to generate a report on test results.  If I build the project locally, I can find the report files under the project's "target/surefire-reports" directory, which includes an xml file with the test details and a formatted HTML report version for viewing.

However, when I trigger the build from Google Cloud Build and view "artifacts", all I see is the raw log output from the Maven build.  Is there a way to save the associated Surefire-generated test result files as additional artifacts that can be viewed from the build artifact link on Google Cloud Build?  We are using a cloudbuild.yaml file.  I'm guessing if it can be done, I need to include some custom commands there, but I've not found anything yet on that.

Answer (score 1):

Found better documentation.

https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#artifacts

Just needed to add an artifacts section to the cloudbuild yaml file.  Something like...

artifacts:
objects:
location: 'gs://buildresults/projectx/$BUILD_ID'
paths: ['target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml']